# How to convert a csv to Hashmap if there are multiple values for a key ? (without using csv reader )

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

Here is the link which states the reading of data from csv to Hashmap.
[Convert CSV values to a HashMap key value pairs in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068383/convert-csv-values-to-a-hashmap-key-value-pairs-in-java)
However, I am trying to read a file of csv, in which there are multiple values for a given key. 
Eg:

```
Key  -  Value 
Fruit -  Apple
Fruit -Strawberry
Fruit -Grapefruit
Vegetable -Potatoe
Vegetable -Celery
```

where , Fruit and Vegetable are the keys.

I am using an ArrayList<> to store the values. 
The code I am writing is able to store the keys , but stores only the last corresponding value .
So, when I print the hashmap , what I get is : Fruit - [Grapefruit] Vegetable- [Celery]
How can I iterate through the loop, and store all the values?

Following is the code, which I have written :

```
public class CsvValueReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mp=null;
        try { 

               String csvFile = "test.csv";

               //create BufferedReader to read csv file
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
               String line = "";
               StringTokenizer st = null;

               mp= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

               int lineNumber = 0; 
               int tokenNumber = 0;
                          //read comma separated file line by line
                           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               lineNumber++;


                           //use comma as token separator
                st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tokenNumber++;


                            String token_lhs=st.nextToken();
                            String token_rhs= st.nextToken();

                            ArrayList<String> arrVal = new ArrayList<String>();
                arrVal.add(token_rhs);

                            mp.put(token_lhs,arrVal);

                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("Final Hashmap is : "+mp);

} catch (Exception e) {
               System.err.println("CSV file cannot be read : " + e);
             }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're putting a new `ArrayList` in your map for each value you find. This replaces the old list you had for that particular key. Instead, you should use the existing array list (if it is already there), and add your value to it.

You should therefore replace this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrVal = new ArrayList<String>();
arrVal.add(token_rhs);
mp.put(token_lhs,arrVal);
```

By this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrVal = mp.get(token_lhs);
if (arrVal == null) {
    arrVal = new ArrayList<String>();
    mp.put(token_lhs,arrVal);
}
arrVal.add(token_rhs);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you create a new `arrVal` list every time.
You should try this code

```
ArrayList<String> arrVal = mp.get(token_lhs);
if(arrVal == null) {
    arrVal = new ArrayList<String>();
    mp.put(token_lhs, arrVal);
}
arrVal.add(token_rhs);
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `containsKey()` if you're gonna use `get()` anyway.

Comment: Each time you find the key (i.e. `containsKey()==true`), you will waste time calculating the hashcode again for the `get()`.

Comment: @Joffrey Exactly! Your newest post is actually better.

Answer (score 1):

you have:

```
while readline
    while splitline
        new ArrayList(); and list.add()
        map.put(key, arraylist)
```

so everytime you executed the `map.put()`, a new arrayList would be put into the map, and the value of existing key would be overwritten with the new arraylist. You need first `get` the arrayList from the map, with certain key, and append the value to the arraylist. if key doesn't exist, create a new arrayList.

If you want to save that part of work, you could consider to use some `MultiMap` api, E.g guava `ArrayListMultiMap`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you always initalize a new ArrayList inside your `while (st.hasMoreTokens())` loop, so you will only have the last ArrayList used (containing only the last token of the csv line)