# Convert Covid 19 CSV data values into a hashmap JAVA

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to convert a CSV file with all the COVID19 data of every country into a hashmap as part of my final project(Still considerably more to be done after this, this is simply step one.) I keep running into an out of bounds error when I run the code though.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("owid-covid-data.csv"));
    String line =  null;
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        String str[] = line.split(",");
        for(int i=1;i<str.length;i++){
            String arr[] = str[i].split(":");
            map.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
 }
}
```

This is the error I keep getting.

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at Example.main(Example.java:19)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert CSV values to a HashMap key value pairs in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068383/convert-csv-values-to-a-hashmap-key-value-pairs-in-java)

Comment: If cell value doesn't have a ":" in it (maybe a blank/empty cell) then line at `map.put(arr[0], arr[1]);` will throw this error. You should add a check that arr.length >= 2.

Comment: I would recommend using a CSV parser instead of rolling your own.